# Jquery Mobile 1.2.0 Alpha 1 popup and dynamic listview

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, listview, jquery-mobile, popup

I have ran into an issue getting my mobile apps ready for 1.2 changes and upgrades. When working with the new popup I have found a couple errors that I have realized and hacked to get working.

1. You can not separate the `<a>` from the `<div>` tag when creating the popup. Seems jQm is looking for the `<a data-rel>` and `<div data-role>` to be within the same div wrap(may be wrong on this, just speculation).

   - if anyone knows if this is just because it is alpha please let us know, because popup was based off of dialog and dialog does not have this problem
2. You can not call the generation of a popup and then call the opening of that popup right after.

   - You have to give `$('#selector').popup()` a few seconds to work before calling it to open, so easy fix is to wrap a setTimeout around your open.
   - `setTimeout('$('#selector').popup("open")',100);`

Just wanted to share and hopefully save someone a lot of wasted time fiddling with the alpha release.

Here is some Jsfiddle I put together so you can see what I mean.
http://jsfiddle.net/2VGZX/31/

Answer (score 0):

If the popup div is located into the page div, the `$('#selector').popup().popup('open')` will work fine.

I don't really understand your problem with the `<div>` and `<a>`.